# Success or error call back in AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#loginForm").submit(function (e)
{
    var Data = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    var PostData =
    {
        "CompanyName": $(this).serializeArray().CompanyName,
        "Username": $(this).serializeArray().Username,
        "Password": $(this).serializeArray().Password
    }
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: formURL,            
        data: PostData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Data" + data);
            alert("Jq" + jqXHR);
            alert("textStatus" + textStatus);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Failed..ajax error response type " + textStatus);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
})
});

$("#loginForm").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
```

This is a simple Ajax request to the C# code,that i have.I know for sure that the C# is giving a correct value(according to the situation).

C# return `true` or `false` as per the situation.But in any case this Ajax script neither giving me a alert window which i have coded for.

Instead i get this response from

`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">false</boolean>`

When `false` and just the value in the tag changes when its true.
Can anyone tell me why neither `success` or `error` is not working.

Comment: How do you debug it? Is submit handler called? It looks like you are trying to submit FORM before binding handler and so the FORM is submited because no default behaviour prevented

Comment: I'd move preventDefault to the top.

Comment: @A.Wolff today is the first day i am dealing with AJAX and javascripts.. so i have no idea what you just asked :P

Comment: @Kunal0615 Put a console.log or alert in submit handler, what happen? You have to learn how to debug javascript code

Comment: @A.Wolff dont stall me here... on that.. your help is much appreciated

Comment: Open network tab in your browser in developer tool and check what response you getting from server.

Comment: Remove the explicit form submission: `$("#loginForm").submit();`. You are handling this through the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

As you can tell from it's name the `.serializeArray()` method returns an array -- not an object. The array is of the form:

```
[
  {
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "b",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    name: "c",
    value: "3"
  }
]
```

- *array of objects*
- Ref: http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/
- **What you need**: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Therefore to access the third `value` you would need to supply the index 2 -- `..[2].value` ... `name` `...[2].name`. Your code has errors that would prevent the ajax call from being made. Is it possible that error is coming from somewhere else?

Therefore change:

```
var PostData =
{
    "CompanyName": $(this).serializeArray().CompanyName,
    "Username": $(this).serializeArray().Username,
    "Password": $(this).serializeArray().Password
}
```

To:

```
var PostDate = $(this).serialize();
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say,my knowledge is limited in this field

Comment: One quick way to learn is to use dev tools' `console.log()` method. You can have the following lines at the very top of the `submit` event handler: `e.preventDefault(); console.log( $(this).serialize() ); console.log( $(this).serializeArray() );` Then look the the dev tools' console -- usually accessed by pressing F12.

Answer (score 0):

Something that make work better is this:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize())
        .done(function (results) {
        alert(results);
    })
        .fail(function (error) {
        alert(error);
    })
        .always(function () {
        alert("AJAX Complete");
    });
});
```